# Can we use L'hopital's rule for this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can we use l'hopital's rule to find the limit of $\frac{n}{t}\log(1+\frac{t}{n})$ as $n$ goes to infinity? My confusion with this is that, although we know that the logarithm is differentiable at 1, we are not differentiating with respect to the variable $n$ we are letting vary.

Comment: Regard $n$ as real-valued variable. This is legit in view of the following simple observation: $$\text{if} \quad \lim_{\substack{t\to\infty \\ \text{along real}}} f(t) = \ell, \qquad \text{then} \quad \lim_{\substack{n\to\infty \\ \text{along integer}}} f(n) = \ell. $$ So, you can use whatever tools that are available to you, L'Hospital's rule for instance, to attack the continuum limit instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $f\colon[1,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac xt\log\left(1+\frac tx\right)=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac tx\right)}{\frac tx}$. You can apply L'Hopital's Rule to it.

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative hint :**

You don't really need L'Hospital's. Observe that :

$$\frac{n}{t}\log\left( 1 + \frac{t}{n}\right) = \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n}{t}} \right)^\frac{n}{t}$$

Recall now that :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

Comment: in my analysis course the rigorous sequence of proofs chose a particular route where this fact is not 'yet' known

Answer (score 0):

You can use L'Hoptial's rule provided that you have an indeterminate form of the following types:

- $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$
- $\dfrac{0}{0}$

For the function you mentioned:

$\dfrac{n\log(1+\frac{t}{n})}{t} = \dfrac{\log(1+\frac{t}{n})}{\frac{t}{n}}$, which is of the second form so you can apply L'Hoptial's rule.